# How to specify messages for single rules within a declaration

Tags: json, object, lint, scss-lint, stylelint

I am trying to adjust my property-blacklist in `stylelint` and want to provide a message to each property that is blacklisted, like I did below with the `top-property`.

```
"property-blacklist": [
  "top",
  {
    "message": "Use translateY instead."
  }
]
```

If I now just want to simply add a custom message for the left-property, then how do I do this? The following configuration does not work:

```
"property-blacklist": [
  [
    "top",
    {
      "message": "Use translateY instead."
    }
  ],
  [
    "left",
    {
      "message": "Use translateX instead."
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one custom message can be assigned to each rule. The [documentation](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#custom-messages) suggests writing a custom formatter if you need more control:

> Writing a [custom formatter](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs//developer-guide/formatters.md) gives you maximum control if you need serious customization.

Alternatively, you could [write a plugin](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/plugins.md). For example, `plugin/property-no-box-offsets`, which would disallow [box offset properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#box-offsets-trbl). You can then generate, within the plugin itself, specific messages for each of the offsets e.g. "Unexpected box offset property. Use translateY instead" for occurrences of the `top` property.